# x86_64 - Why is timing a program with rdtsc/rdtscp giving unreasonably large numbers?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, rdtsc

I'm trying to time a subroutine using rdtscp. This is my procedure:

```
; Setting up time
rdtscp                      ; Getting time
push rax                    ; Saving timestamp

; for(r9=0; r9<LOOP_SIZE; r9++)
mov r9, 0
lup0:
call subr
inc r9
cmp r9, LOOP_SIZE
jnz lup0

; Calculating time taken
pop rbx                     ; Loading old time
rdtscp                      ; Getting time
sub rax, rbx                ; Calculating difference
```

if `LOOP_SIZE` is small enough, I get consistent and expected results. However, when I make it big enough (around 10^9) I spike from 10^9 to 10^20.

```
; Result with "LOOP_SIZE equ 100000000"
971597237
; Result with "LOOP_SIZE equ 1000000000"
18446744072281657066
```

The method that I'm using to display the numbers displays them as unsigned, so I imagine that the large number displayed is actually a negative number and an overflow happened. However, `971597237` is not even close to the 64 bit integer limit, so, assuming that the problem is an overflow, why is it happening?

Comment: `rdtsc` annoyingly puts its result in EDX:EAX even in 64-bit mode.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtsc.  You're only saving / using the low 32 bits of the TSC, and getting a 32-bit unsigned difference, sign-extended to 64-bit because you're computing it with `sub rax, rbx` on the zero-extended 32-bit values instead of `sub eax, ebx`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that [as per documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtscp),  the value of `rdtscp` is not stored on `rax`, but on `edx:eax` (which means that the high bits are on `edx` and the low bits on `eax`) even on 64 bit mode.

So, if you want to use the full 64-bit value on `rax`, you have to move the higher bits from `edx`:

```
; Setting up time
rdtscp                      ; Getting time
shl rdx, 32                 ; Shifting rdx to the correct bit position
add rax, rdx                ; Adding both to make timestamp
push rax                    ; Saving timestamp

; [...stuff...]

; Calculating time taken
rdtscp                      ; Getting time
pop rbx                     ; Loading old time (below rdtscp)
shl rdx, 32                 ; Shifting rdx to the correct bit position
add rax, rdx                ; Adding both to make timestamp
sub rax, rbx                ; Calculating difference
```

*Edit: Moved `pop rbx` one line down, below `rdtscp`. As pointed out by Peter, some registers (rax, rdx and rcx) may be clobbed by `rdtscp`. In your example that's not a problem, but if you decided to `pop rcx` there instead, then it'd probably get overwritten by `rdtscp`, so it's good practice to only pop the stack after it.*

---

Also, you can avoid two calls to the stack by saving the old timestamp in a register that your subroutine doesn't use:

```
; Setting up time
rdtscp                      ; Getting time
shl rdx, 32                 ; Shifting rdx to the correct bit position
lea r12, [rdx + rax]        ; Adding both to make timestamp, and saving it

; [...stuff (that doesn't use r12)...]

; Calculating time taken
rdtscp                      ; Getting time
shl rdx, 32                 ; Shifting rdx to the correct bit position
add rax, rdx                ; Adding both to make timestamp
sub rax, r12                ; Calculating difference
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Normally you'd use a call-clobbered register like rsi or r8 that you don't need to save/restore around your function, instead of RBX.  (`rdtscp` clobbers RCX).  Or instead of the stack, you can merge halves into another register with `shl rdx,32` / `lea r8, [rdx + rax]`, choosing a register your timed region doesn't modify.

Comment: There's no need to guess about what registers `rdtscp` touches.  It writes RDX, RAX, and RCX.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtscp.  But yeah, since you don't need (or want) the `pop` in the timed region, you can just pop into RCX, if you insist on using the stack at all instead of a register to hold the old time.  Then you don't need to touch any registers that RDTSCP didn't already destroy.

Comment: *but if you decided to pop rcx instead, then it'd probably get overwritten by rdtscp* - No, not if you `pop` *after* `rdtscp` like you're doing now.  My comment was based on the original version, which popped inside the timed region, and unfortunately I didn't think of just popping after.

Comment: `add rax, rdx` / `mov r8, rax` can be replaced by `lea r8, [rdx + rax]` like I suggested originally, which is cheaper on all CPUs in essentially all ways that might matter.  Also, if what you're timing is a "subroutine", if it follows the standard calling convention you might want to pick a call-preserved register like `r12`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, the edit is based on the version on the question, which has `pop ebx` before `rdtscp`. And regarding `lea` comment: Updated :^)

Comment: Well the way you state it (right after and in the same paragraph as "Edit: Moved pop rbx one line down") results in what looks like a nonsensical claim about further improvements to your proposed working answer.